# Expression syntax for parent_table.field_name

Tags: jasper-reports

If my JasperReport report shows data from a SQL query like this:

```
SELECT 
"invoices"."invoice_id", 
"invoices"."name", 
"invoices"."contact_id", 
"relationship_contacts"."name", 
FROM "invoices"
LEFT JOIN "contacts" AS "relationship_contacts" ON ("invoices"."contact_id" = "relationship_contacts"."contact_id")
```

how should I specify invoices.name and relationship_contacts.name in JRDesignExpression.setText()? This does not seem to be valid:

```
$F{relationship_contacts.name}
```

Comment: Could you post the snippet of your jrxml file with query and fields?

Comment: @AlexK, it is here, but it wouldn't be very helpful, because it's generic code, and the JOINS (and resulting possible ambiguity of field names) will only happen with particular reports:
https://gitorious.org/online-glom/gwt-glom/blobs/master/src/main/java/org/glom/web/server/ReportGenerator.java#line434

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally in iReport you would just click "Read Fields" to run the query and have iReport define all of the returned fields and fields in the report. In your case it seems that the name of the field isn't exactly what you think in the SQL result set. Try specifying it explicitly:

```
SELECT
  "relationship_contacts"."name" as the_name
FROM ...
```

then this will definitely work: `$F{the_name}`

Comment: Yes, I just tried iReport and noticed that it creates an alias for each field and uses that later in the $F{} syntax in the XML.

For instance, `SELECT contacts."name" AS contacts_name ...`


I guess it does that to work around this problem. It would be nice if this was documented or just not necessary.

Thanks for the help.